# Import .mhx and export .stl on blender

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, export, import, makehuman

I am working on animation project using MakeHuman, blender and Mathematica. I use makeHuman to model a person and get .mhx file. I import this file into blender, I do some modification on pose and export it as .stl to use it on mathematica. I remark that exported .stl file seems empty because its size 84 bytes and when I import it on mathematica it does not work. So what is the problem and How can I deal with? thanks.

[image]

Comment: Are you using the File > Export menu or the 3D printing toolbox to export the STL? The 3D printing toolbox bit exports selected objects only AFAIK.

Comment: @TLousky, I edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

OK, apparently even when you export to STL through the File > Export menu, you must select all before exporting. If your mesh is not selected, it will not be exported.

Do note that non-mesh objects will not be exported either (curves, armatures, etc).

In short, select all objects in your scene (<kbd>A</kbd>), then export to STL.

Answer (score 0):

To export correctly the mesh, I think that we select just the first layer as mentioned below. I tried it and it works correctly on mathematica.

[image]